How to propagate and clear thread context across JVMs for dynamic debug logging
I am trying to implement dynamic debug logging by populating a ThreadContext with specific attributes and filtering logs based on those attributes.
Here’s what I have achieved so far:
Within the same JVM:

For reactive flows, the thread context is passed correctly to all reactive and non-reactive flows using the contextWrite() method and cleared after the chain is completed.
For ExecutorService, I wrap the Callable in a ContextExecutorService to manage the ThreadContext.
answer referred : Dynamically set DEBUG or INFO logging level per request based on request header in reactive Spring Boot with Log4j2

Issue across JVMs:
In a distributed system (e.g., Hazelcast), where a process is submitted to another JVM, the context must be manually passed in a field and set in the thread context of the target JVM. example process that is submitted to another JVM :
@Slf4j
public class LoggingEntryProcessor<K, V, R> implements EntryProcessor<K, V, R>, HazelcastInstanceAware {

  private final EntryProcessor<K, V, R> processor;
  private Map<String, String> attributes;

  @Override
  public R process(Entry<K, V> entry) {
    // Ensure thread context is populated with attributes received from caller JVM and cleared after work is done
    return processor.process(entry); 
    //the process method is nonreactive and may have reactive code inside of it. 
  }
  
  private ContextSnapshot setContextSnapshot(Map<String, String> attributes) {
    // tried creating a snapshot with which i can wrap, Slf4jThreadLocalAccessor is registered in ContextRegistry in this JVM
    new Slf4jThreadLocalAccessor().setValue(attributes);
    return ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().build().captureAll();
  }
}

I tried to wrap the process call like this:
try (Scope scope = contextSnapshot.setThreadLocals()) {
    return processor.process(entry);
}

Problems

Sometimes the thread context leaks, and data is not cleared after processing.
Unpredictable behavior when passing and managing the ThreadContext in distributed scenarios.

Questions

How can I correctly set and clear the thread context in distributed systems like Hazelcast?
Is there a better approach to propagate and manage context across JVMs?
How can I avoid thread context leaks in such scenarios?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not sure is this would be of help to you or not, but I had a similar issue I wanted to pass informaton to the logger but i have some information that goes through hazelcast and some other goes through ActiveMQ, I dont manipulate the ThreadContext myself but I rely on Slf4j MDC (https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html) as you can easily configure your logger to get information from it, this class has the methods getCopyOfContextMap() and  setContextMap(Map<String,String> contextMap)
so I just send a map as part of the message for ActiveMQ and I update it when it comes back so I have the same information on both sides on the MDC object once activemq returns.

if we set it via setContextMap(Map<String, String> contextMap), some code must clear the context after the thread completes the process. how did you handle that? Also, if the thread changed within the process, MDC has to be propagated to the next thread, did you write any code to handle that as well?

about clearing the context, you can clear the map using the method clear() of the same class, for the second scenario i dont have that problem so I dont neet to propagate it any further I just get it to and from activemq
