DynamicThresholdFilter not applying to specific package in Log4j2
I am trying to apply a DynamicThresholdFilter in Log4j2 to filter logs for a specific package (com.example.orange). My goal is to enable DEBUG/TRACE logs dynamically for this package only, based on a custom MDC key (requestLogLevel).
Here's the configuration I am using for the specific package logger:
# Appenders
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=Console
appender.console.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.follow=true
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=${LOG_PATTERN}

logger.app.name=com.example.orange
logger.app.level=warn
logger.app.additivity=false
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref=Console

# Dynamic threshold filter: supposed to apply DEBUG for only the com.example.orange package
logger.app.filter.type=DynamicThresholdFilter
logger.app.filter.key=requestLogLevel
logger.app.filter.defaultThreshold=WARN
logger.app.filter.onMatch=ACCEPT
logger.app.filter.onMismatch=NEUTRAL
logger.app.filter.keyValuePair.type=KeyValuePair
logger.app.filter.keyValuePair.key=TRACE
logger.app.filter.keyValuePair.value=TRACE
logger.app.filter.keyValuePair[1].type=KeyValuePair
logger.app.filter.keyValuePair[1].key=DEBUG
logger.app.filter.keyValuePair[1].value=DEBUG

However, this configuration does not enable DEBUG logs for com.example.orange when I set the requestLogLevel to DEBUG or TRACE in the MDC. The logs still adhere to the default threshold WARN.
If I move the DynamicThresholdFilter to a global filter, like this:
# Appenders
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=Console
appender.console.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.follow=true
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=${LOG_PATTERN}

filter.console.type=DynamicThresholdFilter
filter.console.key=requestLogLevel
filter.console.defaultThreshold=WARN
filter.console.onMatch=ACCEPT
filter.console.onMismatch=NEUTRAL
filter.console.keyValuePair.type=KeyValuePair
filter.console.keyValuePair.key=TRACE
filter.console.keyValuePair.value=TRACE
filter.console.keyValuePair[1].type=KeyValuePair
filter.console.keyValuePair[1].key=DEBUG
filter.console.keyValuePair[1].value=DEBUG

It works, but it applies the filter globally to all packages, enabling DEBUG/TRACE logs for all packages(example spring, micrometer classes used in the code flow) in my application flow, which is not the intended behavior.
Troubleshooting I tried so far:

Verified that the requestLogLevel MDC key is set correctly.
Ensured that logger.app.additivity is set to false to avoid inheriting configurations from the root logger.
Confirmed that the global DynamicThresholdFilter works as expected but applies globally to all packages.

How can I configure the DynamicThresholdFilter to apply only to the specific package (com.example.orange), without affecting other loggers? Is there a way to scope the filter or override the behavior?

The Java Properties configuration format does not follow a uniform set of rules like the other configuration formats: it has several quirks to make it less verbose (see Java Properties format quirks).
In particular:

To add a filter to a component use a filter.<id> prefix instead of just <id>.

Therefore you need to add an additional <id> to your properties:
logger.app.filter.0.type=DynamicThresholdFilter
logger.app.filter.0.key=requestLogLevel
logger.app.filter.0.defaultThreshold=WARN
logger.app.filter.0.onMatch=ACCEPT
logger.app.filter.0.onMismatch=NEUTRAL
logger.app.filter.0.keyValuePair.type=KeyValuePair
logger.app.filter.0.keyValuePair.key=TRACE
logger.app.filter.0.keyValuePair.value=TRACE
logger.app.filter.0.keyValuePair[1].type=KeyValuePair
logger.app.filter.0.keyValuePair[1].key=DEBUG
logger.app.filter.0.keyValuePair[1].value=DEBUG

